# Differences between storing uploaded files in an array vs json in Rails Active Record (Postgresql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, activerecord, carrierwave

I'm building a Ruby on Rails app with Carrierwave using Active Record and Postgres.

I wonder what are the differences (pros/cons) for storing multiple file uploads in a column as array vs json. What is the convention?

I've followed this tutorial: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/README.md#multiple-file-uploads